# Latex Copyright Page

Tags: graphics

I am writing my thesis and I am trying to create a single PDF page which has my  university's logo on the bottom left of the page.

Also the following text should be located below the logo:

"Copyright © (my name) 
All rights reserved."

I cant seem to figure out how to create this page since it want to import it in my main file which is a predefined latex template.

Any help would be nice,
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: We need more information here, since you're using a "predefined [LaTeX] template." That is, do you execute `\maketitle` and everything should appear nicely? Or do you have access to fiddle with the front matter components. We need this information in order to adequately address your problem. Please provide at least a link to this "predefined [LaTeX] template."

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% ...

\clearpage

\vspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}

Copyright \textcopyright\ (my name) All rights reserved.

\clearpage

% ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\vspace*{\fill}` instead of `\leavevmode\vfill`